# Exploratory factor analysis using oblique and bifactor rotation : different pattern loadings

Tags: factor-analysis, factor-rotation

When I try to compare oblique rotated factor analysis (promax, ML) with bifactor rotated analysis (ML), I get different pattern loadings. I don't know which solution should be retained; I am planning to use EFA to decide which pattern to be used for bifactor approach to MGFCA. Generally, when I read about bifactor solution, the pattern is identical to one produced by oblique rotated factor analysis in many, many examples.

Here's my syntax, and an example of pattern loadings :

```
MLFAwhite4<-factanal(datawhite3, factors=4, rotation="promax")
print(MLFAwhite4, digits=3, cutoff=.05)

Loadings:
          Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 Factor4
   spatrels   0.458   0.072                 
   visaudit   0.566           0.058   0.051 
   verbcomp   0.261  -0.065   0.668         
   vismatch           0.520  -0.080   0.247 
   analsyn    0.637                   0.064 
   numrev            -0.099  -0.135   0.813 
   concform   0.758                         
   picrecog   0.289   0.133                 
   memwords          -0.152   0.114   0.606 
   geninfo                    0.885  -0.087 
   retrieve  -0.092   0.220   0.283   0.153 
   audatten           0.398   0.055   0.082 
   decisions          1.002          -0.167

BIFACTORwhite5ml<-fa(r=datawhite3, nfactors=5, max.iter=100, warnings=TRUE, rotate="bifactor", fm="ml")
print(BIFACTORwhite5ml, digits=3, cutoff=.05)

Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
            ML1    ML2    ML3    ML4    ML5    h2    u2  com
spatrels  0.423  0.057 -0.003  0.114  0.186 0.229 0.771 1.58
visaudit  0.604  0.004  0.063  0.103  0.262 0.448 0.552 1.45
verbcomp  0.672 -0.040  0.482  0.035  0.052 0.689 0.311 1.84
vismatch  0.513  0.427 -0.090 -0.046 -0.107 0.467 0.533 2.12
analsyn   0.621 -0.034 -0.016  0.289 -0.016 0.471 0.529 1.42
numrev    0.626 -0.036 -0.176 -0.239 -0.078 0.487 0.513 1.51
concform  0.691 -0.039  0.061  0.276  0.092 0.567 0.433 1.38
picrecog  0.298  0.110  0.030  0.007  0.293 0.188 0.812 2.29
memwords  0.553 -0.091  0.007 -0.269 -0.012 0.387 0.613 1.51
geninfo   0.585  0.003  0.616 -0.008 -0.019 0.722 0.278 2.00
retrieve  0.405  0.188  0.170 -0.045 -0.186 0.265 0.735 2.32
audatten  0.371  0.324  0.034 -0.080  0.069 0.255 0.745 2.16
decisions 0.402  0.761  0.004  0.016  0.019 0.742 0.258 1.52
```

The pattern here is generally different from an oblique rotated factor analysis. Maybe the syntax is incorrect ? If it's correct, then, what should I do (conclude) at this point, considering my final goal is to conduct CFA with bifactor approach ?

Thank you.

Comment: It is the first time I've heard of "bifactor rotation" (shame on me). Can explain it or give a source where it is explained? Also, your first analysis  seem to extract 4 factor and the second - 5 factors. And the programs are different (factanal vs fa) - did you make sure that they return the same results under all other conditions being equal?

Comment: If you don't like the term, let's just say it's an exploratory factor analysis using bifactor method. There is a reason why I added one factor in the bifactor method. The first factor, as you can see, is a general factor (on which all variables load), and all other factors are group/specific factors. And in the first method, which is a common approach to EFA, you get only specific factors, not the general factor. I generally also see authors do it like this. As for the difference between factanal and fa, there is none. You can do factanal or fa using fm=ml and you get exact same results.